# Exposing SCTP port from docker container to host

Tags: docker, containers, sctp

My docker container (sctp server) is running on sctp with port number 36412. However, my sctp client on the host machine unable to communicate with the container. How do I expose this port from container to host? Is it not same as TCP/UDP?
When I run `docker run -p 36412:36412 myimage`, I get below error.

```
Invalid proto: sctp
```

Answer (score 4):

From [reading source code](https://github.com/docker/go-connections/blob/v0.4.0/nat/nat.go), the general form of the `docker run -p` option is

```
docker run -p ipAddr:hostPort:containerPort/proto
```

Critically, the "protocol" part of this [is allowed to be](https://github.com/docker/go-connections/blob/v0.4.0/nat/nat.go#L116) any of `tcp`, `udp`, or `sctp`; it is lowercased, and defaults to `tcp` if not specified.

It looks like for your application, you should be able to

```
docker run -p 36412:36412/sctp ...
```

Comment: Thakns David for the answer. I understand the syntax you mentioned. I tried that already. Apparently, docker does not have support for sctp protocol. I am getting "Invalid proto: sctp". Not sure if there is an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Use the -p flag when running to to map an open port on your host machine to the container port.  The below example maps port 36412 on the host to 36412 in the container.

`docker run -p 36412:36412 mysctpimage`

To view the ports running on your container and where they are mapping to:

`docker port <containerId>`

This will tell you what port and protocol the container is mapping to your host machine.  For example running a simple WebApi project may yield:
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768

[Docker Port Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/#description)

[How to publish or expose a port when running a container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)